# PostgreSQL: query and return array from 3 related tables

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have 3 tables with this structure:

**cities**

```
id  city
1   London 
2   Madrid 
3   Paris
```

**users**

```
id  name
1   Bob
2   John
3   Laura
```

**cities_users** (this table links both previous tables)

```
id  city_id   user_id
1     1          1
2     2          2
3     1          3
4     3          3
```

This way we can easily reference where a user has lived.
E.g. here, we see that user 1 (Bob) lived in London, and user 3 (Laura) lived in London and Paris.

My question is: Which query should I do to obtain this desired result?

```
city_id  city   number_users  users
1        London    2          Bob,Laura
2        Madrid    1          John
3        Paris     1          Laura
```

The count part I think I have it with 
`SELECT c.id, c.city, coalesce (aux.c_count,0) AS number_users FROM cities c 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT city_id, count(*) c_count FROM cities_users GROUP BY city_id ) aux ON aux.city_id = c.id;`

But the array part is the one I can`t manage to solve.

I created a : [DB fiddle for this example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r7SFtx3puzZLTYwgxPdMmC/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using one of those [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html): `string_agg(expression, delimiter)` or `array_agg(expression)` if you really want array of text, instead of one text string with values delimited by comma.

```
SELECT c.id, c.city, count(aux.user_id) AS number_users, string_agg(u.name, ',') AS users
  FROM cities c 
  LEFT JOIN cities_users aux ON aux.city_id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = aux.user_id
 GROUP BY c.id, c.city;

id  city    number_users    users
1   London  2               Bob,Laura
2   Madrid  1               John
3   Paris   1               Laura
```

You don't have to use subquery, it looks cleaner this way. It will have different execution plan, so check your performance just in case.

Comment: Absolutely incredible!, both in efficiency and answering speed. I'm still a beginner in SQL and havo so much to learn... Now I'm not allowed to upvote, but when I can I will come back to this post and upvote you, for sure. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, especially with such well formulated questions that also include fiddle to test answers. I believe you can still accept answers, so that other members looking for unanswered questions will not see this one.